# How to delete that are not attached to VM through Rest Calls

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-bpm

I am new to BPM , softlayer and REST. I completed creating storages (performance and endurance). Now I need to know How will I be able to delete the storages that are not attached to any Virtual Machines. I did not find any thing related to this. Please make a needful favour. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/createObject

Method: POST

Json Payload:

{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "accountId": 202019,
      "items": [
        {
          "billingItemId": 65959265,
          "immediateCancellationFlag": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How to get the `billingItemId` information and `account id`?

Execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/4494893/getObject?objectMask=mask[accountId,username,billingItem.id]

Method: GET
```

If you don’t know the `Network Storage id`, please execute this request using the `username`:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectFilter={"networkStorage": {"username": {"operation": "storageName"}}}&objectMask=mask[billingItem]

Method: GET
```

**References:**

[SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/createObject)

[SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getObject)